# biblatex: force \cite not to ignore semicolon

Tags: biblatex, citing

By default the `\cite` command ignores a semicolon if it follows a dot. How can I force `biblatex` to print the semicolon regardless if there is a dot before?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author = {Foo, Bar},
title = {Foobar},
year = {2016},
location = {Baz}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\footnote{\cite[12]{test}; \cite[12~f.]{test}; \cite[12~ff.]{test}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(And yes, I know that in general I should use `\cites`. But for technical reasons I cannot in this case.)

Comment: Don't do it like that, use the proper thing: `\footcites` which can handle multiple keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[ngerman,english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\textheight}{9cm}
\begin{document}

Sugar, spice and everything
nice\footcites[12]{aristotle:physics}[12\psq]{aksin}[12\psqq]{companion}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
Der Leguan liegt auf der
Lauer\footcites[42]{nietzsche:historie}[84\psq]{knuth:ct:a}[96\psqq]{vangennep}
\selectlanguage{english}
Please don't do it like that\footnote{\cite[12]{companion};
\cite[12\psq]{aksin}; \cite[12\psqq]{ctan}}

\end{document}
```

[image: tomFootcites]

Comment: Not citing a cooking book with recipes concerning liver? ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as mentioned in my question I cannot change the syntax for technical reasons which means that I have to use `\footnote` and `\cite`.

Comment: @Tom Test my answer, look at the output, compare your input.

Answer (score 5):

[Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/37907/johannes-b) has already given the [best answer for this situation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296396/35864). But people might find that they have to write a postnote with a `.` in it for which `biblatex` does not already provide a convenient command (as it does for the "sq."/"f." and "sqq."/"ff.": `\psq` and `\psqq`).

The problem arises because `biblatex` tries very hard to avoid double punctuation and even scans ahead for punctuation after its `\cite` commands. It finds that the postnote `12~f.` ends with a period and doesn't want that to crash with the semicolon afterwards, so the semicolon is swallowed.

You can tell `biblatex` that the `.` in `12~f.` is not a sentence end period (which would clash with a semicolon), but an  abbreviation dot (which is fine before a semicolon) with `\isdot`

```
\cite[etc.\isdot]{sigfridsson};
```

Comment: The amazing thing is, that people use the same bibkeys over and over again for normal case examples.  :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B I have become quite fond of it over the time ;-). The first thing I did when I copied the MWE was to throw out `\jobname.bib` and just use `biblatex-examples.bib`.

Comment: The same here :-)

Comment: A longer, more detailed discussion is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511738/35864