# A Full Stop Suppresses the Delimiter Between Citations

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I have a problem with the delimiter between multiple citations when using Biblatex-Chicago (compiling with `XeLaTeX`). Normally when citing multiple sources with `\cites` or `\autocites`, a semicolon appears between each source cited, but if the page-range ends with a full stop, this delimiter disappears for some reason.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{DelimTestBib.bib}

\begin{document}

Here be dragons \autocites[57ff.]{Sievers1893}[33]{Kloekhorst2008}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The test bibliography file contains these two entries:

```
@book{Sievers1893,
author = "Eduard Sievers",
title = "Altgermanische Metrik",
date = "1893",
publisher = "Max Niemeyer",
address = "Halle",
}

@book{Kloekhorst2008,
author = "Alwin Kloekhorst",
title = "Etymological Dictionary of the Hittite Inherited Lexicon",
date = "2008",
publisher = "Brill",
address = "Leiden",
}
```

This gives me the following output:

[image]

Ideally the citation would be '(Sievers 1893, 57ff.; Kloekhorst 2008, 33)'. Obviously this can be corrected manually (by putting [57ff.;] as the page-range, for instance), but I'd like to have a more automatic solution if there is one.

I should mention that this problem occurs whether I use authordate style or footnotes.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Very good minimal example!

Comment: See also [biblatex: force \cite not to ignore semicolon](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296390/35864)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511738/35864

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually simpler: the period in “ff.” should not be sentence ending, so the rules of LaTeX say it should be followed by `\@`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sievers1893,
author = "Eduard Sievers",
title = "Altgermanische Metrik",
date = "1893",
publisher = "Max Niemeyer",
address = "Halle",
}

@book{Kloekhorst2008,
author = "Alwin Kloekhorst",
title = "Etymological Dictionary of the Hittite Inherited Lexicon",
date = "2008",
publisher = "Brill",
address = "Leiden",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Here be dragons \autocites[57ff.\@]{Sievers1893}[33]{Kloekhorst2008}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(I used `filecontents` just to make the example self-contained, as usual.)

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, I thought it was `\@` before the full-stop to get a sentence-ending space and `\␣` afterwards to get an interword space instead of a sentence-ending one?

Comment: @Au101 `\@.` is for telling LaTeX that the period *is* sentence ending. The manual also describes `.\@` for the converse.

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about that, thanks for the extra nugget of information :) +1

Comment: In the bibliography `biblatex` actually changes the space factor of several punctuation marks. It therefore has its own macro to mark up abbreviation dots: `\isdot`. So `\autocites[57ff.\isdot]{Sievers1893}[33]{Kloekhorst2008}` would be more `biblatex`-y to turn the `.` into a dot, but in the specific case of "f."/"ff." in page numbers `\psq` and `\psqq` as suggested in Ulrike's answer are much nicer.

Answer (score 8):

You should better use `\psqq` instead of an hard coded `ff` and customize it to your needs. But at least you should use `\adddot` instead of a period:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  sequens = {f\adddot},
  sequentes = {ff\adddot},
}

\renewcommand\sqspace{}

\begin{document}

Here be dragons \autocites[57\psqq ]{Sievers1893}[33]{Kloekhorst2008}.

\autocites[57ff\adddot ]{Sievers1893}[33]{Kloekhorst2008}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Needless to say that if the OP writes in German (and TeX knows about it) `\psq` and `\psqq` already give "f." and "ff.".

Comment: This certainly works, thanks - but what's the advantage of this approach over egreg's suggestion? Simply the flexibility should I ever want to use sqq. instead?

Comment: Yes, the flexibility is preserved, not only for the string but also the spacing, e.g. if you want a small space before the ff. Also with \psqq the number is identified as number, and so some styles can e.g. add pp. before it. `55\psqq` can be formated as `pp. 57 sqq.`, but `55ff.\@` will always be `55ff.`.